# nginx reverse proxies with separate SSL termination and websockets

Tags: nginx, ssl, reverse-proxy, websocket

I'm trying to chain proxies. The first one for SSL, next one - for dispatching to the servers.

The first one (`secure-gateway-nginx`) just unwraps SSL and passes to the `gateway-nginx`:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name secure-gateway-nginx;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://gateway-nginx.default.svc.cluster.local/;
    }
}
```

The second one (`gateway-nginx`) dispatches to the `central-broker-mqtt` and the `app` servers:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name gateway-nginx;
    location /mqtt {
        proxy_pass            http://central-broker-mqtt.default.svc.cluster.local/;
        proxy_http_version    1.1;
        proxy_set_header      Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header      Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_connect_timeout 1;
    }
    location /app {
        proxy_pass            http://app.default.svc.cluster.local/;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the websockets for mqtt don't work. The `proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;` line is meaningless since `$http_upgrade` turns out empty for example.

The direct dispatch from the SSL termination to mqtt works fine:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name secure-gateway-nginx;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;
    location /mqtt {
        proxy_pass            http://central-broker-mqtt.default.svc.cluster.local/;
        proxy_http_version    1.1;
        proxy_set_header      Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header      Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_connect_timeout 1;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://gateway-nginx.default.svc.cluster.local/;
    }
}
```

But I'd like to keep the nginx that does SSL just for SSL. How to do that?

**EDIT:**

This appears to work:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name secure-gateway-nginx;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://gateway-nginx.default.svc.cluster.local/;
        proxy_http_version    1.1;
        proxy_set_header      Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header      Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_connect_timeout 1;
    }
}
```

Will it have any side effects?

Comment: If you've answered your question please add it as an answer. Why are you using two Nginx instances when one would like be all that's really needed?

Comment: People don't usually read answered questions and I need a feedback on it because there is no certainty. Why two? When reconfiguring the inner one, you can't mess up the SSL configuration and world-facing endpoints.